# Add Javascript and css to Sharpoint point 2010

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2010, content-editor

I am using Sharepoint 2010, In Content editior part I am trying to use a js file using following tag:

```
<script src="JS/jquery.jOrgChart.js"></script>
```

In same way I am also attaching Jquery file, these are working fine without sharepoint. But when it comes to sharepoint content editior with correct path name for document library it's not working. 
Please suggest a method or if any new tags to use in sharepoint

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your javascript files into the style library folder and reference the files from there.

You can access the style library folder from SharePoint designer.

After you have places your javascript files and stylesheets in the style library folder. you can reference them this way:

```
<script src="/Style%20Libary/JS/jquery.jOrgChart.js"></script>
```